# Unable to push latest software update in Loki

Tags: release-loki, updates

For some reason I'm unable to update this. It's only 25.3 MB(29 components).
I get the message 'waiting for package manager lock', but this disappears and the updates do not happen.

I've never had any problems with standard elementary OS updates before.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards
Nick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for package manager lock what does that mean?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/waiting-for-package-manager-lock-what-does-that-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Tried via terminal?

```
sudo apt-get update && upgrade
```