# On Juno, updates authentication dialog crashes on loop

Tags: updates, security, release-juno

Since yesterday nights, there are those updates:
[image]
When I go on and update, there is on loop a crashing authentication dialog that shows up:

[image]

[image]

The two dialogs are flickering super quickly, you cannot enter the password. I also tried to paste the password, but it does not work.

Any idea?

Outputs are as follow:

```
edo@XPS:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14328 gen 15 14:18 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1

edo@XPS:~$ file /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
/usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=642077ae71b5ca8f6f12f66f0b92e896adbfc68b, stripped
```

**UPDATE**

After the suggested command line, the auth window seems to be fixed. But when I update through AppCenter, I have the following and the update does not start.

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/posts/17951/edit) your question post the output of these commands `ls -l /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1` and `file /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Juno system:

```
→ ls -l /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 14328 gen 15 14:18 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1

→ file /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 
/usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=642077ae71b5ca8f6f12f66f0b92e896adbfc68b, stripped
```

as you can see the executable `polkit-agent-helper-1` has the setuid bit set:

```
-rwsr-xr-x <-- the "s" in "rws"
```

and

```
/usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object <-- file aknowledges the executable has the setuid bit set
```

Looks like on your system the seuid bit "got lost", as the first error shown on your screenshots correctly reports.

A fast workaround is to give the setuid bit explicitly:

```
$ sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

That said, you should investigate on *why* the setuid bit was removed as usually it's not something that "disappears" on itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. With your command now the auth window stopped to freak out. But, when going in AppCenter and launching the pending updates, not much happens, I have updated the original post with a screenshot.

Comment: The only out-of-the-ordinary thing that happened prior to all this, was just the laptop turning itself off (or maybe suspending?) for a 0% battery. Tried a restart too.

Comment: @Travis for the "new" problem, try the solution to [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/waiting-for-package-manager-lock-what-does-that-mean). If it doesn't work I suggest asking a _new_ question instead of editing this one as it might be against the site "etiquette".

Comment: Great, that solution worked too! Thank you very much. I have yet to understand WHY all of this happened though.

Comment: I had the same problem, with no obvious cause. THe solution here (and for the "new" problem also worked for me.